# Sorting Java objects using multiple keys

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, comparable

I've got a collection of Duck objects and I'd like to **sort them using multiple keys**.

```
class Duck {
    DuckAge age; //implements Comparable
    DuckWeight weight; //implements Comparable
    String name;
}
List<Duck> ducks = Pond.getDucks();
```

eg. I want to sort them **primarily by their weights**, and **secondarily by their age**. If two ducks have the exact same weight and the exact same age, then let's differentiate them using their **names as a tertiary key**. I might do something like this:

```
Collections.sort(ducks, new Comparator<Duck>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Duck d1, Duck d2){
        int weightCmp = d1.weight.compareTo(d2.weight);
        if (weightCmp != 0) {
            return weightCmp;
        }
        int ageCmp = d1.age.compareTo(d2.age);
        if (ageCmp != 0) {
            return ageCmp;
        }
        return d1.name.compareTo(d2.name);
    }
});
```

Well I do this quite frequently, but this solution doesn't smell right. It doesn't scale well, and it's easy to mess up. Surely there must be a better way of sorting Ducks using multiple keys! Does anybody know of a better solution?

**EDIT** removed unnecessary `else` branches

Comment: it doesn't look too bad, you can remove one level of indentation, by removing both `else` since in the `if` you return, so it's not needed.

Comment: +1 for getting your ducks in order

Comment: Is there no elegant solution in core Java itself?

Comment: hey i have a question for you....i am totally unaware of how this compare thing works...does your objects "ducks" gets overwritten after being sorted??

Comment: `Collections.sort()` modifies the given collection itself (instead of returning a sorted copy of the collection). So the `ducks` object "gets overwritten" in the sense that it is sorted in-place. (Well not actually in-place: the contents of `ducks` is dumped into an array, where it gets sorted, and the result is copied back into the original collection.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Java 8 solution:

```
Comparator<Duck> cmp = Comparator.comparing(Duck::getWeight)
    .thenComparing(Duck::getAge)
    .thenComparing(Duck::getName);
```

Hooray for lambdas, method references, and default methods:)! Too bad we have to define getters, or use *explicit lambdas*, like so:

```
Comparator<Duck> cmp = Comparator
    .comparing((Duck duck)-> duck.weight)
    .thenComparing((Duck duck)-> duck.age)
    .thenComparing(duck-> duck.name);
```

Type inference won't work with implicit lambdas, so you have to specify the argument type of the first two lambdas. More details in [this answer by Brian Goetz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24442897/212013).

Answer (score 52):

[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) is more elegant:

```
return ComparisonChain.start()
     .compare(d1.weight, d2.weight)
     .compare(d1.age, d2.age)
     .compare(d1.name, d2.name)
     .result();
```

Apache [commons-lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) has a similar construct, [`CompareToBuilder`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/CompareToBuilder.html).

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I wanted! [Guava Ordering](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) class looks nice as well, if you already have some Comparators and want to combine them and use them for sorting.

Comment: Apache's CompareToBuilder is a tiny bit more elegant, since it also handles nulls by default, using a nulls first comparison. Guava's ComparisonChain will throw a NullPointerException unless you add a third parameter (Ordering.natural().nullsFirst()) to every .compare() call.

Comment: How can i use it to sort Arraylists?(using multiple keys)?

Comment: @JB Nizet is there any way i can use it a whole array???here only 2 objects are being sorted

Comment: You create a comparator, and use the code above inside the compare() method of the comparator. Then you sort the list using `Collections.sort(comparator)`, just as shown in the question.

Answer (score 21):

```
List<Duck> ducks = new ArrayList<Duck>();
Collections.sort(ducks, new Comparator<Duck>() {

  @Override
  public int compare(Duck o1, Duck o2) {

    return new org.apache.commons.lang.builder.CompareToBuilder().
        append(o1.weight, o2.weight).
        append(o1.age, o2.age).
        append(o1.name, o2.name).
        toComparison();
  }
});
```

Comment: How can i use it to sort Arraylists?(using multiple keys)?

Comment: Are you talking about arrays (e.g. String[]) or `java.util.ArrayList`s? It depends on the elements that are stored. Arrays can be sorted using the method `Arrays.sort(T[], Comparator<T>)`

Comment: What i meant was,that in this e.g you have just sorted 2 objects of the type duck...."public int compare(Duck o1, Duck o2)" what if i have to sort a whole arraylist of type Duck..for e.g ArrayList<Duck> dd =new ArrayList();  ?????

Comment: That's why you pass the `Comparator` implementation to the `Collections.sort(List<Duck>, Comparator<Duck>)` method which does the job of sorting the whole list. Comparator is there to compare any two elements of the list.

Comment: @BorisPavlović  How do you obtain org.apache.commons.lang?  It doesn't compile.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky add the library to your classpath http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3

Answer (score 14):

Firstly, your solution isn't *that* slow.

If you really want another method, then give each duck a "score" which is essentially a single number that is the sum of their three characteristics, but with a huge weighting (excuse the almost unavoidable pun) for weight, a lesser one for age; and a very small one for the name.

You can allocate ~10 bits for each characteristic, so for each characteristic you have to be in the range `0..1023`.

```
score = ( (weight << 10) + age) << 10 + name;
```

This is probably completely unneeded, but whatever :)

Comment: Nice little trick, thanks. I was going for beauty, not performance, but I'll keep this in mind:)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the CompareToBuilder from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/CompareToBuilder.html). (It explains comparable, but works for Comparator too).

Answer (score 4):

You can use chained `BeanComparators` from Commons BeanUtils:

```
Comparator comparator = new BeanComparator("weight", new BeanComparator("age"));
```

http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanComparator.html

Answer (score 4):

I have just rewritten your code without nested else statements. Do you like it now?

```
@Override
public int compare(Duck d1, Duck d2){
    int weightCmp = d1.weight.compareTo(d2.weight);
    if (weightCmp != 0) {
        return weightCmp;
    }
    int ageCmp = d1.age.compareTo(d2.age);
    if (ageCmp != 0) {
        return ageCmp;
    } 

    return d1.name.compareTo(d2.age);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, it does look better, but the main problem was that I was chaining comparisons manually. The Guava ComparisonChain and Apache CompareToBuilder look much better.