# Sorting values in ArrayList in specific order

Tags: java, sorting, collections

Let me explain the scenario first:

```
List<Row> rowValues = new ArrayList<>();

// After adding values into list
At location 0 = [Johnson, 10000]
At location 1 = [Adam, 12000]
At location 2 = [Mike, 11000]
At location 3 = [Johnson, 17000]
At location 4 = [Tony, 10000]
```

I want to sort elements of `column1` in ascending order and elements of `column2` in descending order. Like:

```
At location 0 = [Adam, 12000]
At location 1 = [Johnson, 17000]
At location 2 = [Johnson, 10000]
At location 3 = [Mike, 11000]
At location 4 = [Tony, 10000]
```

I am not sure whether this can achieve this by using:

```
Collections.sort(rowValues); //or
Collections.sort(rowValues, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Row class, if that makes any sense:

```
final class Row extends ArrayList<Object> implements Comparable<Row> {

    private int index;
    private Order order;


    Row(int initialCapacity) {
        super(initialCapacity);
        this.index = -1; //-1 indicates that the index has not been set
    }

    Object getSortingValue() {
        if (index == -1) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Sorting column is unknown");
        } else if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Row is empty");
        }
        return get(index);
    }

   void setSortingColumn(int index) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (index < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid sorting index: " + index);
        }
        this.index = index;
    }

    Order getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    void setOrder(Order order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Row row) {
        if (row == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        Object sortValue = getSortingValue();
        if (sortValue instanceof Comparable) {
            return ((Comparable) sortValue).compareTo(row.getSortingValue());
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(sortValue + " not type of Comparable");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Row) {
            Row row = (Row) obj;
            return getSortingValue().equals(row.getSortingValue());
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getSortingValue().hashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Create your own class that implements `Comparator<Row>`.  You can have it define the order you want.

Comment: @Lucky_Singh If you edit your post with your `Row` class, I can update my answer with code to achieve what you want.

Comment: @HugoSousa Row class added.

Comment: @Lucky_Singh What are the printed values? (the name and the number?). It looks like there's already a `compareTo` defined. Wasn't you doing this code?

Comment: @HugoSousa the printed values are Name and Salary, the compareTo() code sorts only 1 column, Name...but not the second one..

Comment: @Lucky_Singh Ok, but I don't have access to those things, from the `Row` class, then. I guess you know what to do now, anyway. Here's an example pretty similar to yours, if that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154127/collections-sortlistt-comparator-super-t-method-example

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can sort it using `Collections.sort()`, but you need to define your own `Comparator`, where you define that an object is bigger than other when the first row is bigger, or if they are equal, the second row is bigger.

Answer (score 1):

You need to account for 2 values(for both columns) in compareTo() method, Assuming that corresponding field in the Row object are named name and point -

```
 public int compareTo(Row row) {
        if(!name.equals(row.getName()){
        return name.compareTo(row.getName());
        }
         return  -1 * point.compareTo(row.getPoint());
    }
```

Comment: Should it be `return -1 * point.compareTo(row.getPoint());` since OP wants the second column in descending order? Or is it possible to specify the order dynamically?

Comment: Thank you - edited my answer. The idea was to just show that compareTo() needs to account for 2 properties. We never know what point is - assuming its a String, I have edited the answer so that it is clear on first look.

Comment: Actually, I think it could be dynamic, using some operator. Not sure but take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14154534/1134080). *You also don't need the `equals` since `compareTo` can return `0`, as in that code.*

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to sort by name asc, and if the name is equal to another, then sort by value desc. If so, then

```
    List<Row> rowValues = new ArrayList<Row>();

    // After adding values into list
    rowValues.add(new Row("Johnson", 10000));
    rowValues.add(new Row("Adam", 12000));
    rowValues.add(new Row("Mike", 11000));
    rowValues.add(new Row("Johnson", 17000));
    rowValues.add(new Row("Tony", 10000));

    Collections.sort(rowValues, new RowComparator());

    System.out.println(rowValues);
```

and

```
public class Row {
    private String name;
    private Integer val;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Integer getVal() {
        return val;
    }
    public void setVal(Integer val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
    public Row(String name, Integer val) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.val = val;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Row [name=" + name + ", val=" + val + "]";
    }

}
```

and

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class RowComparator implements Comparator<Row> {

    public int compare(Row o1, Row o2) {
        if (o1.getName().equals(o2.getName())) {
            return -1 * o1.getVal().compareTo(o2.getVal());
        } else {
            return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
        }
    }

}
```