# Sorting a collection using fluent chaining in Java 8

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, comparator, java-stream

Given a class.

```
public class Entity {

    private Long id;
    private String prodName;
    private BigDecimal price;

    // Constructors + getters + setters + hashcode() + equals() + toString().
}
```

Constructing a list of `Entity`.

```
List<Entity> list = new ArrayList<>();

Entity entity = new Entity();
entity.setId(1L);
entity.setProdName("A");
entity.setPrice(new BigDecimal(10));
list.add(entity);

entity = new Entity();
entity.setId(2L);
entity.setProdName("B");
entity.setPrice(new BigDecimal(20));
list.add(entity);

entity = new Entity();
entity.setId(3L);
entity.setProdName("C");
entity.setPrice(new BigDecimal(30));
list.add(entity);

entity = new Entity();
entity.setId(4L);
entity.setProdName("D");
entity.setPrice(new BigDecimal(40));
list.add(entity);

entity = new Entity();
entity.setId(5L);
entity.setProdName("E");
entity.setPrice(new BigDecimal(50));
list.add(entity);

entity = new Entity();
entity.setId(6L);
entity.setProdName("F");
entity.setPrice(new BigDecimal(60));
list.add(entity);

entity = new Entity();
entity.setId(7L);
entity.setProdName("F");
entity.setPrice(new BigDecimal(60));
list.add(entity);
```

Attempting to sort the list in descending order by `price` and `prodName` and then in ascending order by `id`.

```
Comparator<Entity> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Entity::getPrice).reversed();
comparator = comparator.thenComparing(Entity::getProdName).reversed();
comparator = comparator.thenComparingLong(Entity::getId);

list = list.stream().sorted(comparator).collect(Collectors.toList());
// Or Collections.sort(list, comparator);
list.stream().forEachOrdered(l -> System.out.println(l.getId() + " : " + l.getPrice() + " : " + l.getProdName()));
```

After performing sorting, the list should appear like the following.

```
6 : 60 : F
7 : 60 : F
5 : 50 : E
4 : 40 : D
3 : 30 : C
2 : 20 : B
1 : 10 : A
```

But the list, after sorting is performed, appears as follows.

```
1 : 10 : A
2 : 20 : B
3 : 30 : C
4 : 40 : D
5 : 50 : E
6 : 60 : F
7 : 60 : F
```

The sorted list is not according to the given criteria (descending order by `price` and `prodName` and ascending order by `id`).

What more needs to be done?

Comment: Try some code based on the examples provided in this article: http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/007-sort-arraylist-stream-of-objects-in-java8/

Comment: `comparator.thenComparingLong(Entity::getId).reversed()`?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154127/collections-sortlistt-comparator-super-t-method-example) is a good example for collection sort using Comparator.

Comment: You could leave the sorting like it is and use the static call to `Collections.reverse(list)` afterwards

Comment: just get rid of `reveresed()` from your comparator...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're reversing the whole comparator every time you call reversed(). Instead, just do as your description says:

```
Comparator<Entity> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Entity::getPrice,
                                                     Comparator.reverseOrder());
comparator = comparator.thenComparing(Entity::getProdName, 
                                      Comparator.reverseOrder());
comparator = comparator.thenComparingLong(Entity::getId);

list = list.stream().sorted(comparator).collect(Collectors.toList());
list.stream().forEachOrdered(l -> System.out.println(l.getId() + " : " + l.getPrice() + " : " + l.getProdName()));
```

Comment: Of course, programmers who realized that `reversed()` applies to the whole comparator may simply use `Comparator.comparing(Entity::getPrice).thenComparing(Entity::getProdName).reversed() .thenComparingLong(Entity::getId)` to achieve the same…

Answer (score 5):

Consider your code commented:

```
Comparator<Entity> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Entity::getPrice).reversed(); // compare by descending price
comparator = comparator.thenComparing(Entity::getProdName) // then compare by ascending name
                       .reversed(); // then reverse this order: so you now sort by ascending price and descending name
comparator = comparator.thenComparingLong(Entity::getId); // and finally compare by ascending id
```

So the final comparator is: ascending price, descending name then ascending ID, which is exactly what you have as result.

So, the mistake is that you are chaining incorrectly the calls to `reversed()`.

The following will work:

```
Comparator<Entity> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Entity::getPrice).reversed(); //sort by descending price
comparator = comparator.thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(Entity::getProdName).reversed()); // then sort by descending name
comparator = comparator.thenComparingLong(Entity::getId); // then sort by ascending id
```