# Collections.sort having multiple fields java

Tags: java, sorting, collections

```
public class CandidateClass {
    double val;
    String location;
}
```

How do I sort the following list using the field **val**

```
List<CandidateClass> candidateClasses = new ArrayList<CandidateClass>();
```

Comment: Provide a custom `Comparator`; implement the `Comparable` interface

Comment: This is already answered - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154127/collections-sortlistt-comparator-super-t-method-example/14154185#14154185

Answer (score 1):

You do like this:

```
public class CandidateClass implements Comparable<CandidateClass> {
    double val;
    String location;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(CandidateClass o) {
        if (val > o.val) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (val < o.val) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now it can be Comparable.

```
Collections.sort(candidateClasses );
```

Comment: Thanks #Adil for the answer. It works as I need.

Comment: http://www.javatbrains.com/2015/05/how-to-sort-list-of-objects-in-java.html