# Sorting Hashset Object in ascending order

Tags: java, sorting, collections, hashset

I have two `User` `List` objects, merged:

```
objectList1.addAll(objectList2);
```

To avoid duplicates converted to a `HashSet`:

```
Set<User> users = newHashSet(objectList);
```

How can I sort the users in ascending order based on First Name?

I tried to use `TreeSet`, in place of `HashSet` but that throws `Exception`.

How can I achieve the result without making the `User` class to implement 
`Comparable<User>`?

Comment: Collections.sort(Collection<T>, Comparator<T>)

Comment: Can you explain in detail, how I will pass the result set to compare

Comment: "I tried to use Treeset , in place of Hashset but that throws Exception" - then you probably didn't specify an appropriate comparator.

Comment: You may create your own comparator class.

Comment: You must specify some sort of comparator, whether built into the `User` class or whether you made your own `Comparator`.

Comment: Can you explain in detail , how can i achieve this by using own Comparator

Comment: Look at the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement the Comparable Interface. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Or use a Comparator.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Either one should work. The problem is that the Set can't know how to sort itself if it doesn't know how to compare two elements.

Say you want to use Comparator on your User you can define one like this:

```
Comparator<User> comparator = new Comparator<User>() {
   @Override
   public int compare(User u1, User u2) {
      return u1.name.compareTo(u2.name);
   }
};
```

Comment: These interfaces have hardly changed, it will still work the same way!

Comment: Is there any easy way to move the Hashset to Treeset

Comment: Yes, once you've implemented Comparable it should be as easy as this:
`Set<User> users = new TreeSet(objectList);`

Comment: Is there any other way , I can achieve the result without making user class comparable

Comment: Well you could use the Comparator, but you've gotta give the program something to compare two instances, otherwise the program can't know what "ascending order" means in that context. Do you want to order them by their Username?

Comment: @CorkKochi Yes, give the `TreeSet` constructor a `Comparator<User>`. That way you won't need to change the `User` class.

Comment: @Andreas thats something I am looking for, but I got confused in how can i pass the result object , can you give the code to implement to get a correct idea

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz  Yes I want to order them by their Username

Comment: @ Luka Jacobowitz Thanks a million , the next doubt is , where I will pass the resultObject in this case

Comment: You might want to ask another question if you help on a different problem, if this Answer helped you, please upvote and accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz  This link helped me to get the answer in detail which I was searching for , You helped me to reach here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154127/collections-sortlistt-comparator-super-t-method-example