# How to get the nearest future date from the list of dates when passed a certain date?

Tags: java, date

How can I get the nearest future date from a list of dates with compared to the date I pass?
For example, I have list of 3 class objects which has dates property 10 January, 20 January and 30 January respectively. And I have one date object which is 15 January.
Now when I pass date 15 Jan, it should return object of 20 January.
and if I pass date 25 January , it should return object of 30 January.
Is that even possible?

Comment: yes it is possible. try the methods `date.before(date2)` and `date.after(date2)`. with these its possible

Comment: Easiest way is to order the list then loop through comparing the adjacent list elements. If the list is large, look into writing a comparison in conjunction with a common search algorithm.

Comment: Also duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2592501. Please search Stack Overflow before posting.

Answer (score 3):

You search through the list of dates, ignore any dates that are before your reference date, then remember the earliest of those dates.

Remembering the earliest date is like a regular loop for finding the minimum value.

Example:

```
private static Optional<LocalDate> findNext(LocalDate refDate, LocalDate[] dates) {
    LocalDate next = null;
    for (LocalDate date : dates)
        if (! date.isBefore(refDate) && (next == null || date.isBefore(next)))
            next = date;
    return Optional.ofNullable(next);
}
```

*Test*

```
LocalDate[] dates = { LocalDate.of(2016, 1, 10),
                      LocalDate.of(2016, 1, 20),
                      LocalDate.of(2016, 1, 30) };
System.out.println(findNext(LocalDate.of(2016, 1,  5), dates));
System.out.println(findNext(LocalDate.of(2016, 1, 15), dates));
System.out.println(findNext(LocalDate.of(2016, 1, 25), dates));
System.out.println(findNext(LocalDate.of(2016, 2,  1), dates));
```

*Output*

```
Optional[2016-01-10]
Optional[2016-01-20]
Optional[2016-01-30]
Optional.empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the collection by date using [Collections.sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154127/collections-sortlistt-comparator-super-t-method-example)
and iterate over the list comparing the current date passed as parameter and using Calendar class identify the smaller difference by [API to identify difference between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)