# How can I sort an ArrayList from a certain point in each element

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an ArrayList in one of my Java 15 project classes, which looks something like this:

`ArrayList<String> myList = [Student1:15, Student2:38, Student3:87; Student4:10]`

The ArrayList holds Strings where each element is the name of the student and their exam mark, with a colon in between.

The aim is to sort this list in order of lowest to highest mark. How would one go about doing that?

Comment: By writing a custom comparator that splits on the ":" ... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property for example. There are literally dozens, if not hundreds of examples on this site alone.

Comment: Unless there came up something new since Java 8: Use a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Comment: And note: the "real world" answer: java is a statically typed language. So: use proper types. Meaning. Instead of working with raw strings **mangling** information using some "clever" formatting ... just create a Student class, and a class that models Marks.

Comment: And yes, that advice doesnt directly solve your problem. But rest assured: when you properly model your classes and create helpful abstractions, any kind of "client" code that you have to write to actually "do things" becomes way easier to write.

Comment: Someone suggested myList.sort(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.substring(o.indexOf(":"))));
which works for any numbers < 10,000
What do I need to change so that 10,000 or over is correctly identified as bigger than 9999

Comment: @Krombopulos you are using 10,000 with the comma as well?

Comment: @dreamcrash I am not using with a comma. I have students with scores in their thousands (4 digits). They sort fine using the line I wrote in the previous comment. But some students have scores in their ten thousands, which are being treated like 4 digit scores by the comparator line of code for some reason

For example, myList=[Student23:4049, Student45:2938, Student84:10397, Student 97:9123, Student99:21876]
is sorted into
[ Student84:10397, Student99:21876, Student45:2938, Student23:404, Student 97:9123]

Comment: @Krombopulos this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67215898/1366871 should solve that problem

Comment: @dreamcrash It did. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```java
    public static int grade(String s) {
        return Integer.parseInt(s.split(":")[1]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();

        l.add("a:10");
        l.add("b:2");
        l.add("e:2");
        l.add("c:1");


        l.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Main::grade));
        System.out.println(l);
    }
```

Comment: Hell yeah. Thanks a lot dude! That worked

Answer (score 0):

Create an Object that implements Comparator and use Collections sort(List list, Comparator ) method.

[Collections sort(List<T>,Comparator<? super T>) method example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154127/collections-sortlistt-comparator-super-t-method-example)