# Sorting an ArrayList according to 3 customised Strings in Java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, customization

I'm trying to sort characteristics of a Fruit class by name, colour, and weight using an ArrayList in Java. Name, colour and weight are all read in as strings, in one line, from the user, before creating an instance of the class Fruit. I then need to add the Fruit objects to the ArrayList, and sort them in the order I mentioned before. In other words, first alphabetically according to name, then according to colour, and finally, by weight.

I'm not entirely certain how to implement the sort() method from the ArrayList class. Do you have any suggestions for me? Or perhaps any tutorials to suggest where I can improve my understanding of sort() and ArrayLists?

The code is below.

Thanks!

```
import java.util.*;

/**creates instances of the Fruits class, and stores the
* resulting objects in an array which can be ordered
* firsting alphebetically by name, then by colour, and
* finally, in ascending order by weight
**/
public class Driver
{
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
      int input = 0;

      ArrayList fruitInfo = new ArrayList();

      do
      {
         System.out.println("Enter option: (1) add fruit (2) quit:");
         input = s.nextInt();
         s.nextLine();

         switch(input)
         {
            case 1:{ 
                     System.out.println("Enter name, colour and mass in kg separated by a `enter code here`space");
                     String in = s.nextLine();
                     String[] temp = in.split(" ");

                      //create a new instance of the fruit class and add it to the `enter code here`<ArrayList> {@link ArrayList}, fruitInfo
                     fruitInfo.add(new Fruit(temp[0], temp[1], temp[2]));
                      break;
                   }

            case 2:{
                     break;
                    }

            default: System.out.println("Input incorrect. Try again.");
         }
      }
      while(input!=2);
   }
}

/* Class Fruits
* a class modelled on the characteristics of fruit
* each fruit has a name, colour and mass, which are
* stored as <Strings>
**/

public class Fruit
{
private String name;
private String col;
private String kg;

/* Constructor
* constructs an instance of the Fruit class
* using user defined characteristics
**/

public Fruit(String name, String colour, String mass)
{
   this.name=name;
   col=colour;
   mass=kg;
} 
}
```

Comment: This could be a possible repeat of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036429/sorting-java-objects-using-multiple-keys

Answer (score 1):

Have your Fruit class implements Comparable and implement your compare logic in

```
public class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit>
...

   public int compareTo(Fruit otherFruit) {
   ... your compare logic here ....
   }

}
```

then you can sort your list with Collections.sort(myList);

Answer (score 1):

You should implement a comparator

```
public class FruitComparator implements Comparator<Fruit> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Fruit f1, MyObject f2) {
       if(!f1.getName().equals(f2.getName())) return f1.getName().compareTo(f2.getName()));
       if(!f1.getColor().equals(f2.getColor)) return f1.getColor().compareTo(f2.getColor()));
       if(!f1.getWeight().equals(f2.getWeight())) return f1.getWeight().compareTo(f2.getWeight()));

    }
}
```

Now you can use the `Collections.sort` method with your new comparator:

```
Collections.sort(fruitInfo, new FruitComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this code.

```
import java.util.*;

/**
 * creates instances of the Fruits class, and stores the resulting objects in an
 * array which can be ordered firsting alphebetically by name, then by colour,
 * and finally, in ascending order by weight
*
 */
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = 0;

        ArrayList<Fruit> fruitInfo = new ArrayList<>();

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter option: (1) add fruit (2) quit:");
            input = s.nextInt();
            s.nextLine();

            switch (input) {
                case 1: {
                    System.out.println("Enter name, colour and mass in kg separated by a `enter code here`space");
                    String in = s.nextLine();
                    String[] temp = in.split(" ");

                    //create a new instance of the fruit class and add it to the `enter code here`<ArrayList> {@link ArrayList}, fruitInfo
                    fruitInfo.add(new Fruit(temp[0], temp[1], temp[2]));
                    Collections.sort(fruitInfo);
                    break;
                }

                case 2: {
                    break;
                }

                default:
                    System.out.println("Input incorrect. Try again.");
            }
        } while (input != 2);
    }
}

/* Class Fruits
 * a class modelled on the characteristics of fruit
 * each fruit has a name, colour and mass, which are
 * stored as <Strings>
 **/
class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit> {

    private String name;
    private String col;
    private String kg;

    public int compareTo(Fruit otherFruit) {
        int nameCmp = name.compareTo(otherFruit.name);
        if (nameCmp != 0) {
            return nameCmp;
        }
        int colCmp = name.compareTo(otherFruit.col);
        if (colCmp != 0) {
            return colCmp;
        }
        return kg.compareTo(otherFruit.kg);
    }
    /* Constructor
     * constructs an instance of the Fruit class
     * using user defined characteristics
     **/

    public Fruit(String name, String colour, String mass) {
        this.name = name;
        col = colour;
        mass = kg;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Fruit class implements the java Comparator Interface (look this up on google), this can be done by using Collections.sort.
I tried to implement this into your code:

```
import java.util.*;

/**creates instances of the Fruits class, and stores the
 * resulting objects in an array which can be ordered
 * firsting alphebetically by name, then by colour, and
 * finally, in ascending order by weight
 **/
public class Driver
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = 0;

        ArrayList fruitInfo = new ArrayList();

        do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter option: (1) add fruit (2) quit (3) to print sorted by name (4) to print sorted by kg:");
            input = s.nextInt();
            s.nextLine();

            switch(input)
            {
                case 1:{
                    System.out.println("Enter name, colour and mass in kg separated by a `enter code here`space");
                    String in = s.nextLine();
                    String[] temp = in.split(" ");

                    //create a new instance of the fruit class and add it to the `enter code here`<ArrayList> {@link ArrayList}, fruitInfo
                    fruitInfo.add(new Fruit(temp[0], temp[1], temp[2]));
                    break;
                }

                case 2:{
                    break;
                }
                case 3:
                    Collections.sort(fruitInfo, Fruit.FruitNameComparator);
                    for(Object fruit:fruitInfo) {
                        System.out.println(fruit);
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Collections.sort(fruitInfo, Fruit.FruitKgComparator);
                    for(Object fruit:fruitInfo) {
                        System.out.println(fruit);
                    }
                    break;
                default: System.out.println("Input incorrect. Try again.");
            }
        }
        while(input!=2);
    }
}
```

And the Fruit class:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Fruit implements Comparator<Fruit>
{
    private String name;
    private String col;
    private String kg;

/* Constructor
* constructs an instance of the Fruit class
* using user defined characteristics
**/

    public Fruit(String name, String colour, String mass)
    {
        this.name=name;
        col=colour;
        kg=mass;
    }

    public static Comparator<Fruit> FruitNameComparator = new Comparator<Fruit>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Fruit o1, Fruit o2) {
            return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
        }
    };
    public static Comparator<Fruit> FruitColComparator = new Comparator<Fruit>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Fruit o1, Fruit o2) {
            return o1.col.compareTo(o2.col);
        }
    };
    public static Comparator<Fruit> FruitKgComparator = new Comparator<Fruit>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Fruit o1, Fruit o2) {
            return o1.kg.compareTo(o2.kg);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int compare(Fruit o1, Fruit o2) {
        return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name + " Colour: " + col + " Weight: " +kg;
    }
}
```

And here an example output:

```
Enter option: (1) add fruit (2) quit (3) to print sorted by name (4) to print sorted by kg:
1
Enter name, colour and mass in kg separated by a `enter code here`space
a b c
Enter option: (1) add fruit (2) quit (3) to print sorted by name (4) to print sorted by kg:
1
Enter name, colour and mass in kg separated by a `enter code here`space
b c a
Enter option: (1) add fruit (2) quit (3) to print sorted by name (4) to print sorted by kg:
1
Enter name, colour and mass in kg separated by a `enter code here`space
c a b
Enter option: (1) add fruit (2) quit (3) to print sorted by name (4) to print sorted by kg:
3
Name: a Colour: b Weight: c
Name: b Colour: c Weight: a
Name: c Colour: a Weight: b
Enter option: (1) add fruit (2) quit (3) to print sorted by name (4) to print sorted by kg:
4
Name: b Colour: c Weight: a
Name: c Colour: a Weight: b
Name: a Colour: b Weight: c
```