# Very confused by Java 8 Comparator type inference

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, java-8, comparator

I've been looking at the difference between `Collections.sort` and `list.sort`, specifically regarding using the `Comparator` static methods and whether param types are required in the lambda expressions. Before we start, I know I could use method references, e.g. `Song::getTitle` to overcome my problems, but my query here is not so much something I want to fix but something I want an answer to, i.e. why is the Java compiler handling it in this way.

These are my finding. Suppose we have an `ArrayList` of type `Song`, with some songs added, there are 3 standard get methods:

```java
ArrayList<Song> playlist1 = new ArrayList<Song>();

//add some new Song objects
playlist.addSong( new Song("Only Girl (In The World)", 235, "Rihanna") );
playlist.addSong( new Song("Thinking of Me", 206, "Olly Murs") );
playlist.addSong( new Song("Raise Your Glass", 202,"P!nk") );
```

Here is a call to both types of sort method that works, no problem:

```java
Collections.sort(playlist1, 
        Comparator.comparing(p1 -> p1.getTitle()));

playlist1.sort(
        Comparator.comparing(p1 -> p1.getTitle()));
```

As soon as I start to chain `thenComparing`, the following happens:

```java
Collections.sort(playlist1,
        Comparator.comparing(p1 -> p1.getTitle())
        .thenComparing(p1 -> p1.getDuration())
        .thenComparing(p1 -> p1.getArtist())
      );
  
playlist1.sort(
    Comparator.comparing(p1 -> p1.getTitle())
      .thenComparing(p1 -> p1.getDuration())
      .thenComparing(p1 -> p1.getArtist())
    );
```

i.e. syntax errors because it does not know the type of `p1` anymore. So to fix this I add the type `Song` to the first parameter (of comparing):

```java
Collections.sort(playlist1,
            Comparator.comparing((Song p1) -> p1.getTitle())
            .thenComparing(p1 -> p1.getDuration())
            .thenComparing(p1 -> p1.getArtist())
            );
    
playlist1.sort(
        Comparator.comparing((Song p1) -> p1.getTitle())
        .thenComparing(p1 -> p1.getDuration())
        .thenComparing(p1 -> p1.getArtist())
        );
```

Now here comes the CONFUSING part. For p`laylist1.sort`, i.e. the List, this solve all compilation errors, for both the following `thenComparing` calls. However, for `Collections.sort`, it solves it for the first one, but not the last one. I tested added several extra calls to `thenComparing` and it always shows an error for the last one, unless I put `(Song p1)` for the parameter.

Now I went on to test this further with creating a `TreeSet` and with using `Objects.compare`:

```java
int x = Objects.compare(t1, t2, 
    Comparator.comparing((Song p1) -> p1.getTitle())
    .thenComparing(p1 -> p1.getDuration())
    .thenComparing(p1 -> p1.getArtist())
    );
    
    
Set<Song> set = new TreeSet<Song>(
    Comparator.comparing((Song p1) -> p1.getTitle())
    .thenComparing(p1 -> p1.getDuration())
    .thenComparing(p1 -> p1.getArtist())
    );
```

The same thing happens as in, for the `TreeSet`, there are no compilation errors but for `Objects.compare` the last call to `thenComparing` shows an error.

Can anyone please explain why this is happening and also why there is no need to use `(Song p1)` at all when simply calling the comparing method (without further `thenComparing` calls).

One other query on the same topic is when I do this to the `TreeSet`:

```java
Set<Song> set = new TreeSet<Song>(
            Comparator.comparing(p1 -> p1.getTitle())
            .thenComparing(p1 -> p1.getDuration())
            .thenComparing(p1 -> p1.getArtist())
            );
```

i.e. remove the type `Song` from the first lambda parameter for the comparing method call, it shows syntax errors under the call to comparing and the first call to `thenComparing` but not to the final call to `thenComparing` - almost the opposite of what was happening above! Whereas, for all the other 3 examples i.e. with `Objects.compare`, `List.sort` and `Collections.sort` when I remove that first `Song` param type it shows syntax errors for all the calls.

Edited to include screenshot of errors I was receiving in Eclipse Kepler SR2, which I have now since found are Eclipse specific because when compiled using the JDK8 java compiler on the command-line it compiles OK.

[image: Sort errors in Eclipse]

Comment: It would be helpful if you include in your question all the compilation error messages you are getting in all your tests.

Comment: to be honest, I think it would be easiest for someone to see what the issues are by running the source code themselves.

Comment: What are the types of `t1` and `t2` in the `Objects.compare` example? I'm trying to infer them, but layering my type inference over the compiler's type inference is intractable. :-)

Comment: Also what compiler are you using?

Comment: Yeah, the error with `Comparator.sort` happens with Eclipse's, but not the JDK's compiler.

Comment: I am using Eclipse Kepler SR2 with patches for Java 8. Also, t1 and t2 are of type Song, sorry, should have posted: Song t1 = new Song("Only girl in world", 238, "Rhianna"); Song t2 = new Song("Other song", 99, "Rhianna");

Comment: Stuart Marks - another question I have for you is does the comparing and thenComparing methods use the compareTo method on the value passed to them, e.g. if a string is passed p1.getTitle() then I assume the compareTo method is used to compare the two title strings? I realised this by creating a field in my Song class of a custom type, e.g. class Name then trying to pass this to the comparator, e.g. comparing((Song p1) -> p1.getName()) and found it gave me a syntax error until I made the Name class implement Comparable. The javadoc is not clear on this.

Comment: @user3780370 yes the 2nd generic type in the `comparing` and `thenComparing` must implement `Comparable` unless you call the overloaded methods which take a 2nd function to do the comparison.

Comment: You've got two separate issues going here.  One of the answerers pointed out you could use method references, which you sorta brushed off.  Just as lambdas come in both "explicitly typed" and "implicitly typed" flavors, method references come in "exact" (one overload) and "inexact" (multiple overloads) flavors.  Either an exact method ref or an explicit lambda can be used to provide additional typing information if not present.  (Explicit type witnesses and casts can also be used, but are often bigger hammers.)

Comment: Note to future readers: Do not post images of error messages. Post the error message as text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

First, all the examples you say cause errors compile fine with the reference implementation (javac from JDK 8.)  They also work fine in IntelliJ, so its quite possible the errors you're seeing are Eclipse-specific.

Your underlying question seems to be: "why does it stop working when I start chaining."  The reason is, while lambda expressions and generic method invocations are *poly expressions* (their type is context-sensitive) when they appear as method parameters, when they appear instead as method receiver expressions, they are not.

When you say

```
Collections.sort(playlist1, comparing(p1 -> p1.getTitle()));
```

there is enough type information to solve for both the type argument of `comparing()` and the argument type `p1`.  The `comparing()` call gets its target type from the signature of `Collections.sort`, so it is known `comparing()` must return a `Comparator<Song>`, and therefore `p1` must be `Song`.

But when you start chaining:

```
Collections.sort(playlist1,
                 comparing(p1 -> p1.getTitle())
                     .thenComparing(p1 -> p1.getDuration())
                     .thenComparing(p1 -> p1.getArtist()));
```

now we've got a problem.  We know that the compound expression `comparing(...).thenComparing(...)` has a target type of `Comparator<Song>`, but because the receiver expression for the chain, `comparing(p -> p.getTitle())`, is a generic method call, and we can't infer its type parameters from its other arguments, we're kind of out of luck.  Since we don't know the type of this expression, we don't know that it has a `thenComparing` method, etc.

There are several ways to fix this, all of which involve injecting more type information so that the initial object in the chain can be properly typed. Here they are, in rough order of decreasing desirability and increasing intrusiveness:

- Use an exact method reference (one with no overloads), like `Song::getTitle`.  This then gives enough type information to infer the type variables for the `comparing()` call, and therefore give it a type, and therefore continue down the chain.
- Use an explicit lambda (as you did in your example).
- Provide a type witness for the `comparing()` call: `Comparator.<Song, String>comparing(...)`.
- Provide an explicit target type with a cast, by casting the receiver expression to `Comparator<Song>`.

Comment: +1 for actually answering the OP "why can't the compiler infer this" rather than just giving workarounds/solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Brian. However, I still find something unanswered, why does List.sort behave differently to Collections.sort, in that the former only requires the first lambda to contain the parameter type, but the latter also requires the last to, e.g. if I have a comparing followed by 5 thenComparing calls I would have to put (Song p1) in the comparing and in the last thenComparing. Also in my original post you will see the bottom example of the TreeSet where I remove all param types and yet the last call to thenComparing is OK but the others are not - so this behaves differently.

Comment: @user3780370 Are you still using the Eclipse compiler?  I haven't seen this behavior, if I understand your question correctly.  Can you (a) try it with javac from JDK 8 and (b) if it still fails, post the code?

Comment: @BrianGoetz Thanks for this suggestion. I have just compiled it within the Command Window using javac and it compiles as you said. It appears to be an Eclipse issue. I've not yet updated to Eclipse Luna, which is purpose-built for JDK8 so hopefully it may be fixed in that. I actually have a screenshot to show you what was happening in Eclipse but don't know how to post on here.

Comment: I think you mean `Comparator.<Song, String>comparing(...)`.

Answer (score 26):

The problem is type inferencing.  Without adding a `(Song s)` to the first comparison, `comparator.comparing` doesn't know the type of the input so it defaults to Object.

You can fix this problem 1 of 3 ways:

1. Use the new Java 8 method reference syntax

   ```
    Collections.sort(playlist,
               Comparator.comparing(Song::getTitle)
               .thenComparing(Song::getDuration)
               .thenComparing(Song::getArtist)
               );
   ```
2. Pull out each comparison step into a local reference

   ```
     Comparator<Song> byName = (s1, s2) -> s1.getArtist().compareTo(s2.getArtist());

     Comparator<Song> byDuration = (s1, s2) -> Integer.compare(s1.getDuration(), s2.getDuration());

       Collections.sort(playlist,
               byName
               .thenComparing(byDuration)
               );
   ```

   **EDIT**
3. Forcing the type returned by the Comparator (note you need both the input type and the comparison key type)

   ```
   sort(
     Comparator.<Song, String>comparing((s) -> s.getTitle())
               .thenComparing(p1 -> p1.getDuration())
               .thenComparing(p1 -> p1.getArtist())
               );
   ```

I think the "last" `thenComparing` syntax error is misleading you.  It's actually a type problem with the whole chain, it's just the compiler only marking the end of the chain as a syntax error because that's when the final return type doesn't match I guess.

I'm not sure why `List` is doing a better inferencing job than `Collection` since it should do the same capture type but apparently not.

Comment: Why does it know it for the `ArrayList` but not for the `Collections` solution (given the first call in the chain has a `Song` parameter)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however, if you read my post you would see I said: "Before we start, I know I could use method references, e.g. Song::getTitle to overcome my problems, but my query here is not so much something I want to fix but something I want an answer to, i.e. why is the Java compiler handling it in this way."

Comment: I want an answer as to why the compiler is behaving that way when I use lambda expressions. It accepts comparing(s -> s.getArtist()) but then when I chain .thenComparing(s -> s.getDuration()) for example it gives me syntax errors for both calls, if I then add a an explicit type in the comparing call, e.g. comparing((Song s) -> s.getArtist()) then this fixes that problem and for the List.sort and TreeSet it also solves all further compilation errors without having to add additional param types, however, for the Collections.sort & Objects.compare examples the last thenComparing still fails

Answer (score 2):

Another way to deal with this compile time error:

Cast your first comparing function's variable explicitly and then good to go. I have sort the list of org.bson.Documents object. Please look at sample code

```
Comparator<Document> comparator = Comparator.comparing((Document hist) -> (String) hist.get("orderLineStatus"), reverseOrder())
                       .thenComparing(hist -> (Date) hist.get("promisedShipDate"))
                       .thenComparing(hist -> (Date) hist.get("lastShipDate"));
list = list.stream().sorted(comparator).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

`playlist1.sort(...)` creates a bound of Song for the type variable E, from the declaration of playlist1, which "ripples" to the comparator.

In `Collections.sort(...)`, there is no such bound, and the inference from the type of the first comparator is not enough for the compiler to infer the rest.

I think you would get "correct" behavior from `Collections.<Song>sort(...)`, but don't have a java 8 install to test it out for you.

Comment: hi, yes you are correct in that adding Collections.<Song> does get rid of the error for the last thenComparing call