# In Java, how do we make a type parameter of a generic to take a type parameter itself?

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter

In Java, how do we make a type parameter of a generic to take a type parameter itself? What I would really like to do is the following:

```
public class TransformerBase<T, TRANSFORMER<U> extends TransformerBase<U, TRANSFORMER>>
{

  public <O> TRANSFORMER<O> transform1(TransformFunction<T, O> f)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

And one would extend the TransformerBase class and add their own transform methods, while retaining the original transform methods in the base class, like this:

```
public class MyTransformer<T> extends TransformerBase<T, MyTransformer>>
{

  public <O> MyTransformer<O> transform2(TransformFunction<T, O> f)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then the user of the class can chain the method calls like this:

```
MyTransformer<String> input = new MyTransformer<>();
MyTransformer<String> result = input
  .transform1(new TransformFunction<String, Integer>() {...})
  .transform2(new TransformFunction<Integer, String>() {...});
```

This is similar to the problem outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164375/subclassing-a-java-builder-class) but with the addition that the "Builder" itself takes a type parameter.

**But the thing is, it does not look like Java supports this kind of construct. Is there another way to solve this problem?**

I tried declaring the base class like this:

```
public class TransformerBase<T, TRANSFORMER extends TransformerBase<T, TRANSFORMER>>
{

  public <O, TFM_OUT extends TransformerBase<O, TFM_OUT>> TFM_OUT transform1(TransformFunction<T, O> f)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

And the extended class:

```
public class MyTransformer<T> extends TransformerBase<T, MyTransformer<T>>
{
  public <O, TFM_OUT extends MyTransformer<O>> TFM_OUT transform2(TransformFunction<T, O> f)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

The user can do this:

```
MyTransformer<Integer> input = new MyTransformer<>();

MyTransformer<String> t = input.transform1(new TransformFunction<Integer, String>(){...});

MyTransformer<Integer> result = t.transform2(new TransformFunction<String, Integer>(){...});
```

But in order for method chaining to work, the caller has to declare the type parameters explicitly, which kind of defeats the purpose of chaining:

```
MyTransformer<String> result = input
  .<String, MyTransformer<String>>transform1(new TransformFunction<Integer, String>(){ ... })
  .transform2(new TransformFunction<String, Integer>(){...});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436871/very-confused-by-java-8-comparator-type-inference

Comment: Yes @shmosel. Thanks for the link. That explains why we need to explicitly specify the types. But if Java can support specifying a type parameter taking another type parameter, this would not be needed...