# Java 8 Comparator comparing doesn't chain

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

Let's say I have a Pair class

```
public class Pair<P, Q> {
    public P p;
    public Q q;


    public Pair(P p, Q q) {
        this.p = p;
        this.q = q;
    }

    public int firstValue() {
        return ((Number)p).intValue();
    }

    public int secondValue() {
        return ((Number)q).intValue();
    }
}
```

And I wish to sort it, first by first value, then by second value. Now' if I do this

```
List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> pairList = new ArrayList<>();
pairList.add(new Pair<>(1, 5));
pairList.add(new Pair<>(2, 2));
pairList.add(new Pair<>(2, 22));
pairList.add(new Pair<>(1, 22));
pairList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Pair::firstValue));
```

Everything works well and good, the list is sorted by first values of pair, but if I do this

```
pairList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Pair::firstValue).thenComparing(Pair::secondValue));
```

It fails with error

```
Error:(24, 38) java: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T,U
(argument mismatch; invalid method reference
  method firstValue in class DataStructures.Pair<P,Q> cannot be applied to given types
    required: no arguments
    found: java.lang.Object
    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Ok,so it might not be able to infer the arguments, so if I do this

```
pairList.sort(Comparator.<Integer, Integer>comparing(Pair::firstValue)
                                          .thenComparing(Pair::secondValue));
```

It fails with error

```
Error:(24, 39) java: invalid method reference
non-static method firstValue() cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Why does it work for comparing() and not for comparing().thenComparing() ?

Comment: Try `Comparator.<Pair, Integer>comparing`.

Comment: @shmosel wow that worked, do you mind adding it as an answer with a reason why it worked! Thanks!

Comment: I suspect you would have fewer problems if you used [Comparator.comparingInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-).

Comment: @VGR Suprisingly not. Type inference with chained comparators is an [old problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24436871/1553851), but can usually be avoided with method references. But there's something about the generic parameters in `Pair` that's causing problems here.

Comment: @MayurKulkarni Please show your `pairList` declaration.

Comment: @shmosel added declaration

Comment: @VGR comparingInt fails in the same way

Comment: @MayurKulkarni It's still the better option since it avoids boxing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error seems to be related to `Pair`'s generic parameters. One workaround it to use an explicit type, as you've attempted:

```
pairList.sort(Comparator.<Pair>comparingInt(Pair::firstValue).thenComparingInt(Pair::secondValue));
//                       ^^^^^^
```

Note the `comparingInt()` which reduces the number of parameters you need to specify, and improves performance by avoiding boxing.

Another solution is to parameterize the type reference:

```
pairList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Pair<?,?>::firstValue).thenComparingInt(Pair::secondValue));
//                                        ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be:

```
pairList.sort(Comparator.<Pair, Integer>comparing(Pair::firstValue)
                                       .thenComparing(Pair::secondValue));
```

First type parameter refers to the type being passed to Comparator. Second type parameter refers to the type that comparator should effectively compare with.