# Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context in java 8 streams

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8

I was playing around with examples from http://www.concretepage.com/java/jdk-8/java-8-unaryoperator-binaryoperator-example.

What I find really confusing is that when I mistakenly put a wrong type into one of generics when forming Collectors, java compiler gives me a very misleading message:

> Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

My error has nothing to do with static vs instance context in reality:

```
Map<String, Map<Integer, Integer>> mapOfStudents = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getClassName,
            Collectors.toMap(Student::getName, Student::getAge)));
```

My mistake is in generic return type. When I correct it and put:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> mapOfStudents
```

everything goes back to normal.

Can someone explain the reason behind such a confusing error message? I'm sure the is a good one, but I fail to grasp it.

**EDIT:**

```
~$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_121"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-8u121-b13-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I get a very different message with `javac` (much clearer). Although I have had similarly bad error messages in Eclipse when using method references/lambdas.

Comment: Please provide the exact make and version of the java compiler, as type inference is one of the things that has been changing quite frequently.

Comment: See Edit section for details. I'm running Intellij Idea 2016.3

Comment: Perhaps it is looking for a non-static getName that returns an Integer, but the compiler breaks off the search as only a static method would qualify.

Comment: But I am not referring to 'this'. Java compiler should be smart enough to understand what a method reference to a arbitrary object is.

Comment: Note the similar message [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42127735/1553851).

Comment: @JornVernee, can you give an example for a bad message in Eclipse? For this example, Eclipse (head) says: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<String,Map<String,Integer>> to Map<String,Map<Integer,Integer>>", which looks very good to me.

Comment: @StephanHerrmann Nothing I can reproduce a at the moment. I tried the question's code, and it looks like you can't use quick-fix to add in the missing methods into `Student` when using method references (a feature that I use all the time). That might actually be the annoyance I was remembering.

Comment: I remember seeing similar misleading error messages in the past, but I can’t reproduce it with the question’s example. Generally, the answer is that the main focus of compiler development is at compiling correct code correctly, not at analyzing the cause of an error. Sometimes, it’s really impressive what a small mistake like a single misplaced character (say a comma or bracket) can cause. Correctly analyzing the problem of a knowingly wrong source code could require an entirely different program…

Comment: @StephanHerrmann indeed, ecj behaves much better here, great job!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

First it should be noted, that the message is issued not by java compiler (javac), but by IntelliJ IDEA. You can see javac messages in "Messages Build" window when you actually launch a build process. What you see in editor window is messages generated by IDEA itself and they could differ.

The error message is misleading due to implementation of method reference resolution in IntelliJ IDEA. It considers non-static method reference to be resolved only if number of corresponding SAM (single abstract method) arguments equals to number of method arguments plus one *and* the first SAM argument type is compatible with method containing class. See [the implementation](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/560b5b026596d553bcc9f62cbb6a7c5e739452bc/java/java-psi-api/src/com/intellij/psi/PsiMethodReferenceUtil.java#L44) (also `isSecondSearchPossible` method above, some additional magic is performed for varargs methods).

It works correctly if your program has no errors. However if you have a mismatched type, the generic arguments of the `Function` passed into `toMap` cannot be substituted, so it remains `Function<T, R>`, and its `apply` method first argument is simply `T` which does not correspond to the type `Student`. Thus so-called "second search" fails and IDEA thinks that the method is referenced from static context. While both static and non-static context are not applicable here, non-static context matches your method better, at least according to the number of arguments as `getName()` method receives no arguments. On the other hand, IDEA logic is "if non-static context is not applicable, then it's a static context", hence the error message.

I would consider this as a bug, or at least as a usability problem. I've just logged it [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-168200) based on [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42237290/4856258). Hopefully we will fix it.

Disclaimer: I'm IntelliJ IDEA developer.

**Update**: fixed in IDEA 2017.2.

Comment: If it doesn't agree with `javac` it's a bug.

Comment: @EJP, it agrees that the program is incorrect, but error message differs. Java language specification specifies what is correct program, but it does not specify exactly how should error messages look for incorrect programs. Note that error messages in Eclipse compiler are also different, and in this case are actually even better, than javac messages in terms that you can easier spot the actual error. Would you consider this as a bug in Eclipse compiler? :-)

Comment: To me,  "non-static & static references" is a far cry from issue of "generic types doesn't match".

Comment: Recent versions of IDEA still have the same issue, at least for map-reduce error messages. tested with 2018.3.6 and 2019.2