# Enum of Functions

Tags: java, enums, functional-interface

Let's say I have two classes

```
class A{
    int a;
    int getA(){
        return this.a;
    }
}
```

and

```
class B extends A{
    String b;
    String getB(){
        return this.b;
    }
}
```

I would like to have an enum, containing all possible values and and getters of inheritance tree (don't ask, I just want to).

```
enum ValueGetters{
    A("a", A::getA),
    B("b", B::getB);

    String parameterName;
    Function parameterGetter;
}
```

I have problem writing constructor for this class.

```
ValueGetters(String parameterName, Function parameterGetter){
    this.parameterName = parameterName;
    this.parameterGetter = parameterGetter;
}
```

returns error for both A and B (`Error:(12, 14) java: incompatible types: invalid method reference`).

The same situation is for `ValueGetters(String parameterName, Function<?,?> parameterGetter)`

For `ValueGetters(String parameterName, Function<? extends A,?> parameterGetter)` this gives error only for B, and if I try to overload constructor with `ValueGetters(String parameterName, Function<? extends B,?> parameterGetter)` I have new error that both types have the same type of erasure.

On the other hand `ValueGetters(String parameterName, Object parameterGetter)` returns error stating that `Object` is not a `Function`.

I have tried to define my own `@FunctionalInterface` but it gave me the same error, and overloading methods of `@FunctionalInterface` to accept both `A` and `B` apparently is not an option (or not an obvious one).

If anyone could propose solution to my problem I would greatly appreciate it.

**EDIT & SOLUTION**

I know it's not exactly an enum, but it works in the same way and provides functionality I needed:

1. Returns getter
2. Getter is type-sensitive
3. Solution does not require any changes in the original class
4. Works well with interfaces

...and now, the code:

```
public class ValueGetter<T extends A, R> {
    private String name;
    private Function<A,R> getter;

    private ValueGetter(String name, Function<A, R> getter){
        this.name = name;
        this.getter = getter;
    }

    private static <T extends A, R> ValueGetter create(String name, Function<T,R> valueGetter){
        return new ValueGetter(name, valueGetter);
    }

    public static ValueGetter<A, Integer> AA = create("a", A::getA);
    public static ValueGetter<B, Integer> BB = create("a", B::getB);

    public Function<T, R> getGetter(){
        return (Function<T, R>) this.getter;
    }
}
```

With this implementation

```
A a1 = new A(12345);
B b1 = new B(54321, "sdfghjk");
System.out.println(ValueGetter.AA.getGetter().apply(a1));
System.out.println(ValueGetter.AA.getGetter().apply(b1));
System.out.println(ValueGetter.BB.getGetter().apply(b1));
```

compiles and works, while line

```
System.out.println(ValueGetter.BB.getGetter().apply(a1));
```

gives compilation error `apply(B) in function cannot be applied to (A)`

Answer (score 1):

One waty to implement it is using a singleton instance of each class:

```
class BB {  // Renamed B to BB to make it work with enum
    String b;
    private static final BB instance = new BB();


    public static BB getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }


    public String getB(){
        return this.b;
    }

    // Example usage with cast
    public String getB(Object b) {
        return ((BB) b).getB();
    }
}

public enum ValueGetters{
    B("b", BB.getInstance()::getB);

    String parameterName;
    Function parameterGetter;

    ValueGetters(String parameterName, Function parameterGetter){
        this.parameterName = parameterName;
        this.parameterGetter = parameterGetter;
    }
}
```

You could the use it like that:

```
ValueGetters.B.getGetter().apply(b);
```

Comment: "non-static method references require object instance" - that's not correct. The method reference can be created using ``A::getA``. You do need an instance but only when you want to invoke the method.

Comment: You completely missed my point; I have many instances of A and B and I want to use getters from this enum like `ValueGetters.A.getGetter().apply(instanceOfA)` and `ValueGetters.B.getGetter().apply(instanceOfB)`. You are referring to `A non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context` but this error is wrong(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42200958/non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-in-java-8-streams). I have used `A::getA`-like construction and it works. My problem is related to storing this type of reference in enum.

Comment: @KarolPokomeda I was referring to why non-static methods cannot be called without an instance. I have tested my solution and still think this solves the problem you are describing. I have used it in the following way: `ValueGetters.B.getGetter().apply(b)`.

Comment: Sorry, I have to give you a credit. Your solution works but it is far from what i expected, as it requires severe modification of original class. And as @f1sh said, you need and instance only when you call. E.g. this code works perfectly:
    
`A a1 = new A(12345);`
`Function<A, ?> function = A::getA;`
`System.out.println(function.apply(a1));`

Comment: Yes, I have modified my answer regarding having the instance of a class to apply the method.

Comment: Without having to change your `A` and `B` classes, you could also create a static map from `String` (enum class name) to `Method`.

Comment: With map I encounter exactly the same problems... I'm starting to believe that i want impossible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144563/discussion-between-karol-pokomeda-and-).

Answer (score 1):

You have two fundamental problems in your `enum`. First, there is a name clash. Your classes are named `A` and `B` and the `enum` constants are named `A` and `B` as well. In all contexts, where an identifier may refer to both, a class or a variable, Java will prefer the variable, hence, you are referring to the `enum` constants `A` and `B` which are in scope with your `A::getA` and `B::getB`.

Further, you are using the *raw type* `Function`, which doesn’t support such specific method references. One way to fix this, is

```
package somepackage;

import java.util.function.Function;

class A{
    int a;
    int getA(){
        return this.a;
    }
}
class B extends A{
    String b;
    String getB(){
        return this.b;
    }
}
enum ValueGetters{
    A("a", somepackage.A::getA),
    B("b", somepackage.B::getB);

    String parameterName;
    Function parameterGetter;

    <T> ValueGetters(String pName, Function<T,Object> f) {
        parameterName=pName;
        parameterGetter=f;
    }
}
```

Note that you need the classes to be in a named `package` to be able to disambiguate the names. There is no way to do that for the unnamed default package.

Further, the `parameterGetter` variable still has the *raw type* `Function`, as there is no way to express a common function type for your two functions having the signatures `A -> Integer` and `B -> String`. You can’t solve this with Generics here, as `enum`s do not support having different type parameters at the constants.

---

You have already found the right solution, going from `enum` to an ordinary generic class, which may define differently typed constants. Naming the constants `AA` and `BB` instead of `A` and `B` also solves the name clash. But you shouldn’t use `Function<A,R>` when `Function<T,R>` is meant, further, you have copy&paste errors.

You can clean this up, simplifying your solution:

```
// you may also declare it as  public class ValueGetter<T extends A, R>,
// but there would be no actual benefit...
public final class ValueGetter<T, R> {
    private String name;
    private Function<T,R> getter;

    private ValueGetter(String name, Function<T, R> getter){
        this.name = name;
        this.getter = getter;
    }
    public static final ValueGetter<A, Integer> AA = new ValueGetter<>("a", A::getA);
    public static final ValueGetter<B, String>  BB = new ValueGetter<>("b", B::getB);

    public Function<T, R> getGetter() {
        return this.getter;
    }
    public String name() {
        return name;
    }
}
```