# Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context inside Collectors.toMap

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of Students which I want to convert into a `Map<String, Integer>`, where the map key should be the first name of the student. To keep the code sample simple, I specified the map value as `1`:

```
final Map<String, Integer> map = someStudents.stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(Student::getFirstName, 1));
```

The compiler complains about:

> non-static method getFirstName() cannot be referenced from a static context

Any idea? I am confused because many examples use the same approach of passing a reference to the non-static method. Why does the compiler see a static context here?

Comment: unfortunately this error is reported too many times in the wrong place

Comment: That's interesting point @Eugene.

Comment: Emdee, can you post full code?

Answer (score 4):

[The value mapper should be a function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-), i.e.:

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getFirstName, s -> 1));
```

The function `s -> 1` essentially takes a student as input and returns `1` in this specific case for the map values.

The below code is not valid as the literal value `1` is not a function.

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getFirstName, 1));
```

Comment: You are correct about second parameter but, the first parameter must be accessed through an object reference. Or, the `getFirstName` must be static.

Comment: @mnmopazem there's nothing wrong with `Student::getFirstName`, infact it's equivalent to `student -> student.getFirstName()` which indeed is an object reference.

Comment: Static members are accessed using class name. In this case, class name is `Student`, note the case.

Comment: @mnmopazem "Or, the getFirstName must be static."  if `getFirstName` is defined as `static String getFirstName() {...}` it would yield a compilation error, first being that you cannot access instance fields in static methods and second in the `toMap` collector. the only case where the method can be `static` and still work is if you defined it as --> `static String getFirstName(Student s) {
        return s.getFirstName();
    }` which I wouldn't recommend doing when you can simply define an instance getter method as `public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }`

Comment: That's interesting as compiler error contradicts method reference access type. May be, OP has error on different line?! What's your take?

Comment: Hm. I suppose both our answers are correct. Did you notice an interesting comment(on question) by Eugene? May be 'thats' the answer. :)

Comment: @mnmopazem well both our answers are correct but you saying " the correct statement is:" `someStudents.stream().collect( Collectors.toMap( student -> student.getFirstName(), student -> 1) );` suggests that using `Student::getFirstName` as the key mapper function is incorrect which is not true.  Yes, I did realise what Eugene meant when i saw his comment earlier. you can read more here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42200958/non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-in-java-8-streams

Comment: @mnmopazem another similar issue answer by Holger --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40172551/static-context-cannot-access-non-static-in-collectors

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you are accessing `getFirstName` using a class name -`Student`(as if its a static memeber) rather than using object reference. [Java tutorial - Method Refrences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).
Secondly, second parameter of `toMap` method must be a [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) type.

So, the correct statement is:
`someStudents.stream().collect( Collectors.toMap( student -> student.getFirstName(), student -> 1 ) );`

**Edit:**
Or, it can also be as posted by @Aomine. Both answers are correct. For more info, refer to comments on @Aomine's answers.

**Edit 2:**
Though, @Aomine's and this answer give expected result, note difference in first parameter.

Comment: `Student::getFirstName` _is the same thing_ as `student -> student.getFirstName()`

Comment: No, its different. To keep it simple, lets the discussion be on your answer as it begin there...

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that first of all, this message is very misleading and that seems to be a java bug.
Second, you are providing an int value in place of a function reference.
Correct is this:

```
final Map<String, Integer> map = someStudents.stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(Student::getFirstName, val -> 1));
```

Here `val -> 1` is a function which for any `val` will always return 1.

Another situation where you would get the same error would be this:

```
 final Map<String, Integer> map = someStudents.stream().collect(
            Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

If `someStudents` is of type `Map<String, String>` but map is `Map<String, Integer>` you would get the same:

`non-static method Map.Entry::getValue cannot be referenced from a static context`