# How does method chaining work in Java 8 Comparator?

Tags: java, java-8, ocpjp

I'm prepping up for the Java 8 certificate and the following has me puzzled a littlebit, maybe someone can help me with this?
In the example, a Squirrel class is modelled. It has a name and a weight. Now you can make a Comparator class to sort this thing using both fields. So first sort by name and then by weight. Something like this:

```
public class ChainingComparator implements Comparator<Squirrel> {
    public int compare(Squirrel s1, Squirrel s2) {

        Comparator<Squirrel> c = Comparator.comparing(s -> s.getSpecies());
        c = c.thenComparingInt(s -> s.getWeight());

        return c.compare(s1, s2);
    }
}
```

So far so good.. but then the puzzling part. Underneath the code example, they state that you can write this in one single line by using method chaining. Maybe I misunderstand, but when I chain the *comparing* and the *thenComparing* parts, I get a compile error. It's got to do with the types of objects that are compared (first String, then int).

Why does it work when I put in an intermediate variable and not when chaining? And is it possible to chain at all?

Comment: try this one `        Comparator<Squirrel> c = Comparator.comparing((Squirrel s) -> s.getSpecies()).thenComparingInt(s -> s.getWeight());`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you chain both, the compiler cannot infer the type argument of the returned comparator of `comparing()`because it depends on the returned comparator of `thenComparingInt()` that itself cannot be inferred.

Specify the type in the lambda parameter of `comparing()` (or use a method reference) and it solves the inference issue as the returned type of `comparing()` could so be inferred. :

```
    Comparator<Squirrel> c = Comparator.comparing((Squirrel s)  -> s.getSpecies())
                                       .thenComparingInt(s -> s.getWeight());
```

Note that specifying the type in the lambda parameter of `thenComparingInt()` (or using a method reference) such as :

```
    Comparator<Squirrel> c = Comparator.comparing(s -> s.getSpecies())
                                       .thenComparingInt((Squirrel s) -> s.getWeight());
```

will not work as the receiver (here the return type of the chained method) is not considered in the inference type computation.

[This JDK 8 tutorial/documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) explains that very well :

> Note: It is important to note that the inference algorithm uses only
>   invocation arguments, target types, and possibly an obvious expected
>   return type to infer types. The inference algorithm does not use
>   results from later in the program.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible - chain `comparing(...)` with `thenComparing(...)` and with `compare(...)` using method references instead of lambda expressions:

```
public int compare(Squirrel s1, Squirrel s2) {
    return Comparator.comparing(Squirrel::getSpecies)
        .thenComparing(Squirrel::getWeight)
        .compare(s1, s2);
}
```

Why does it work this way? I can't explain it better than Brian in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436871/very-confused-by-java-8-comparator-type-inference#answer-24442897) to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436871/very-confused-by-java-8-comparator-type-inference).

Also, this can be rewritten with a 1 line (assuming you have a List of Squirrel that you want to sort):

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Squirrel::getSpecies).thenComparing(Squirrel::getWeight));
```