# Sorting LongAdder in streams

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream

I have

```
Map<String,LongAdder>
```

and I want to sort by the value the best way in streams. This is harder than with Long because LongAdder does not implement Comparable so I have to use longValue (or intValue if using subtraction to make the Comparator).

I know I can use

```
m.entrySet().stream().sorted((a, b) -> b.getValue().intValue() - a.getValue().intValue())
```

but I actually want to also sort secondarily on the key (String). I'm also reversing the sort.

I want to do

```
m.entrySet().stream().sorted(
Comparator.comparing((a, b) -> b.getValue().intValue() - a.getValue().intValue()))
```

so that I can chain more comparators afterward with thenComparing()

The exception is

```
Lambda expression's signature does not match the signature of the functional interface method apply(T)
```

But even declaring a standalone Comparator this does not work:

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<String,LongAdder>> byCount =      Comparator.comparing((a,b) -> 
    (b.getValue().intValue() - a.getValue().intValue()));

Lambda expression's signature does not match the signature of the functional interface method apply(T)
```

I can't use functional reference "::" because it's too many parts: Map.Entry.getValue().intValue().

Comment: `Comparator.comparing` does not take a `Comparator` - it takes a function that maps from your object to a comparable. Also, never use subtraction to compare - it can overflow and give you the wrong results. Use `Integer.compare`. Also, don't use `intValue` if your numbers are actually longs - again, you lose information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Comparator.comparingLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingLong(java.util.function.ToLongFunction)) is what you need:

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<String, LongAdder>> byCount =
    Comparator.comparingLong((Map.Entry<String, LongAdder> e) ->
        e.getValue().longValue()).reversed().thenComparing(...);
```

Important note: don't forget to use an explicitly typed lambda expression, otherwise method chaining like `comparing(...).thenComparing(...)` won't compile in this particular case<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436871/very-confused-by-java-8-comparator-type-inference#answer-24442897) explains why.</sup>

Comment: For one level, you can avoid the explicit types when using `Comparator<Map.Entry<String, LongAdder>> byCount = Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparingLong(LongAdder::sum).reversed( ));` But when chaining another sort criteria, you end up needing explicit types, like `Comparator<Map.Entry <String, LongAdder>> byCount2 = Map.Entry.<String, LongAdder>comparingByValue(Comparator. comparingLong(LongAdder::sum).reversed()).thenComparing(…);`

Answer (score 1):

Your standalone comparator could be fixed to use a `Function` and would look like :

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<String,LongAdder>> byCount = Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e.getValue().intValue());
```