# The type of getMethod() from the type MyClass is String, this is incompatible with the descriptor's return type: U

Tags: java, generics

I have a simple java class with some variables String, Double, Integer etc.

```
public class MyClass {
    private String name;
    private String status;
    private Double risk;
    private Double health;
    // more variables with all getters and setters
}
```

I am trying to write a generic method which will return the `Function<T, U>` type. I will further use this function for sorting. It is throwing compile time error

> The type of getName() from the type MyClass is String, this is incompatible with the descriptor's return type: U

at line `func = MyClass::getName;`

and error

> The type of getRisk() from the type MyClass is Double, this is incompatible with the descriptor's return type: U

at line `func = MyClass::getRisk;`

```
     private static <T extends MyClass, U extends Comparable<U>> Function<T, U> getSortFunction(final String fieldName) {
        Function<T, U> func = null;
        if ("name".equalsIgnoreCase(fieldName)) {
            func = MyClass::getName;
        } else if ("risk".equalsIgnoreCase(fieldName)) {
            func = MyClass::getRisk;
        }
        return func;
    }
```

The return type of my function is of Comparable type not sure what wrong I am doing here. Any pointers?

Comment: It's because the compiler has no guarantee that `U` will be a `String` or `Double` or whatever else you know it to be. You may have to use casting for this, although your real problem may be something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<T extends MyClass, U extends Comparable<U>>`  :  This is type inference problem. This has be discussed in a question:  [Very confused by Java 8 Comparator type inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436871/very-confused-by-java-8-comparator-type-inference)

To fix the problem you can do the following:

- Change the return type: `private static <T extends MyClass, U extends Comparable<U>> Function<T, U>`  to `private static Comparator<MyClass>`?
- Return Comparator.comparing based on the field name:

```
if ("name".equalsIgnoreCase(fieldName)) {
            func = Comparator.comparing(MyClass::getName);
```

Complete code:

```
    private static Comparator<MyClass> getSortFunction(final String fieldName) {
        Comparator<MyClass> func = null;
        if ("name".equalsIgnoreCase(fieldName)) {
            func = Comparator.comparing(MyClass::getName);
        } else if ("risk".equalsIgnoreCase(fieldName)) {
            func = Comparator.comparing(MyClass::getRisk);
        }
        return func;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<MyClass> myClassList = //init list;
        myClassList.sort(getSortFunction("name"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java Generics is all about you as developer promising that the instances used/returned will fulfill some type restrictions.

So, what is it that you promise about the result type of `getSortFunction()`? You write:

```
private static <T extends MyClass, U extends Comparable<U>> Function<T, U> getSortFunction(final String fieldName)
```

meaning:

- The method will return a `Function` accepting `T` and returning `U`.
- The `Function` will accept some unspecified subclass `T` of `MyClass`.
- The `Function` will return instances of `U`, being some `Comparable` class.

When the compiler sees a call of e.g. `getSortFunction("name")`, he has no hint what to conclude for `T` and `U`, whether the resulting `Function` will be a `Function<MyClass,String>` or a `Function<MySubclass,Long>`, so the generics part of your declaration isn't helpful. The compiler's only chance is to look at the expected result of the method call, e.g.

```
Function<MyClass,String> fun = getSortFunction("hometown");
```

In this case, `T` is `MyClass`, and `U` is `String`. Of course, the method body must be written in a way applicable to all possible call patterns, so the same method body must match both a call expecting a `Function<MyClass,String>` and one expecting a `Function<MySubclass,Long>`. Returning `MyClass::getName` only matches the first call pattern and not e.g. a `Function<MySubclass,Long>`.

That's why you get the compile error.

Comment: Since I have declared in the return type(<T extends MyClass, U extends Comparable<U>>) the compiler should use be using that to conclude. T should evaluate to MyClass and U should evaluate to Comparable. The compiler should be using the Comparable instead of evaluating any condition. There is no point in using extends then.

Comment: If you don't want variability in the result type, why do you introduce the type variables T and U at all?