# How to sort files in a stream by partial filename?

Tags: java, java-stream, java-io

I use the following to sort files first by name, then by modification date:

```
Files.list(Paths.get(importDir))
        .map(Path::toFile)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(File::getName).thenComparingLong(File::lastModified))
        .forEachOrdered(file -> System.out.println(file.getName()));
```

Question: how can I refactor the `File::getName` part to only compare based on partial filename, like: `StringUtils.substringBefore(file.getName(), "_")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the method reference with a lambda expression on the `File` object, although you'll have to specify the types (see the additional discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24436871/2422776)):

```java
Files.list(Paths.get(importDir))
     .map(Path::toFile)
     .sorted(Comparator.<File, String> comparing(f -> StringUtils.substringBefore
                                                      (f.getName(), "_"))
                       .thenComparingLong(File::lastModified))
     .forEachOrdered(file -> System.out.println(file.getName()));
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but `f.getName()` cannot be resolved!

Comment: @membersound see my edited answer

Comment: You should close the stream returned by `Files.list()`. See [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#list(java.nio.file.Path))

Comment: @sadetaosa but how?

Comment: `try(Stream<Path> files = Files.list(Paths.get(importDir))) { files.sorted(…).forEachOrdered(…); }`

Comment: Instead of `Comparator.<File, String> comparing(f -> …)` I’d use `Comparator.comparing((File f) -> …)`