# Type Inference in Method Invocation Poly Expression within the Invocation Context with/without method chaining

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, jls, language-specifications

I was going through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436871/very-confused-by-java-8-comparator-type-inference/24442897#24442897) - this triggered the following set of thoughts regarding the Type Inference:

```java
class Song {
  public Integer duration;
  public String artist;
  public String title;
//   ... getters...
}

List<Song> playlist1 = new ArrayList<>();

Collections.sort(Collections.EMPTY_LIST,
        Comparator.comparing((Song p1) -> p1.getTitle())); //-----1

Collections.sort(playlist1,
        Comparator.comparing(p1 -> p1.getTitle())); //----2

Collections.sort(playlist1,
        Comparator.comparing(p1 -> p1.getTitle())
            .thenComparing(p1 -> p1.getDuration()).thenComparing(p1 -> p1.getArtist()));
//----3
```

1. `Collections.sort(..)` is **not a Poly Expression** but a **Standalone Expression**:

   - as the return type of `.sort(...)` is `void` - and the foremost conditions for this to be applicable for method invocation is that its return type must be Type Parameter that also appears in the arguments.
   - and method invocation must occur in the assignment/invocation context
2. `Comparator.comparing(...)` : is a **Poly Expression** as:

   - it occurs in the invocation context and
   - has a return type that is a Type Argument also occurring as the arguments to the method.
3. Thus in,`Collections.sort(playlist1, Comparator.comparing(p1 -> p1.getTitle()));` the expression `Comparator.comparing(p1 -> p1.getTitle())` undergoes the type inference as:

   - Since the target type is `Comparator<Song>`
   - `Comparator.comparing(...)` will use the **Target Type** to determine the **type arguments**
   - and thus infers that `p1` is of type `Song`.
4. but if we consider **Expression-3** we will see **Compilation Error** as:

   - `Comparator.comparing(...).thenComparing(...).thenComparing(...)` - has a **target type** of `Comparator<Song>`
   - this is because for an invocation chain of this type: `ClassType.A().B().C()` the inference will have to proceed from `C() -> B() -> A() -> ClassType`
   - now the problem is that for the compiler - it is complete unknown that **which class is C() belonging to** and hence will **not be able to infer the chain upto `A`**.
   - On the contrary - if the chain had been `ClassType.A()` - the compiler can easily determine that `A()` belongs to `ClassType`.
   - and thus the compiler is unable to determine the `p1` and so on.

**Is my thinking about the above points correct? or am I missing something?**

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly.