# java 8 optional generic strange compilation error

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Here is a piece of code that shows a compilation error that I cannot really explain.

```
List<?> another = new ArrayList<>();
List<?> nullableList = null;

// this Actually works
Optional<List<?>> a2 = Optional.ofNullable(nullableList);
List<?> result = a2.orElse(another);

// THIS IS NOT ALLOWED!!!! COMPILATION ERROR
Optional.ofNullable(nullableList).orElse(another);
```

This is the description of Optional.ofNullable

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> Optional<T> ofNullable(T value) {
    return value == null ? (Optional<T>) EMPTY
                         : new Optional<>(value);
}
```

In our case, T should be `List<?>` so why is it not allowed to do `Optional.ofNullable(nullableList).orElse(another);`

If anybody can explain why the "two steps" is allowed and why the "one step" is not, that would make my day. Thank you.

Comment: *What* is the exact error your getting?

Comment: It's a similar issue to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436871/very-confused-by-java-8-comparator-type-inference

Comment: Type inference with wildcard types is rather weird. When you use `Optional.<List<?>> ofNullable(nullableList).orElse(another);`, it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. They indeed helped me.