# Restrict method reference parameter type

Tags: java, lambda, method-reference

```
Set<String> premiumStrings = new HashSet<>();
Set<String> sortedSet = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(premiumStrings::contains).thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

This doesn't work, because `premiumStrings::contains` can take any object and not just strings. One can replace it with `(String s) -> premiumStrings.contains(s)`, but is there a way to restrict the parameter type while still using a method reference lambda?

(Specifically, the problem is `The method thenComparing(Comparator<? super Object>) in the type Comparator<Object> is not applicable for the arguments (Comparator<Comparable<? super Comparable<? super T>>>)`.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436871/very-confused-by-java-8-comparator-type-inference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Help the compiler a bit with types:

```
Set<String> sortedSet = new TreeSet<>(
                Comparator.<String, Boolean>comparing(premiumStrings::contains).thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

Comment: If you change `o -> ...` to `premiumStrings::contains` then that's exactly what I'm looking for. :)

Comment: Updated - the previous version was a leftover from my refactorings to find out what's going on, sorry ;)

Answer (score 0):

The compiler should infer the types of arguments passed to each method.

And when we have a chain of methods, the context doesn't provide enough information for that. And the argument of every method reference (or lambda expression) would be treated as being of type `Object` and not `String`.

To avoid that, we can provide the type explicitly as a parameter of a lambda expression:

```
Set<String> premiumStrings = new HashSet<>();
    
Comparator<String> comparator = 
    Comparator.comparing((String str) -> premiumStrings.contains(str))
        .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder());
        
Set<String> sortedSet = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
```

Or by using so-called *Type Witness*: `Comparator.<String>comparing().thenComparing()`.

*For more information, [see](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)*.