# Using Lombok @SuperBuilder Using Generic Final Child Class Does Not Compile

Tags: java, generics, lombok, builder

I'm currently facing a problem with Lombok's `@SuperBuilder` annotation and generics. I have an `abstract` parent and a `final` child class. When creating the child using the builder, passing values of the correct type leads to compile errors.

The simplified classes and interfaces

```
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public abstract class Parent<T> {

    private SomeGenericClass<?, Parent<T>> someGenericClass;
    private T value;
}

interface SomeInterface<D> {

}

class SomeGenericClass<D, S> implements SomeInterface<D> {

}

@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
final class Child<T> extends Parent<T> {

}
```

The test code

```
public class SuperBuilderTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeGenericClass<String, Parent<Long>> someGenericClass = new SomeGenericClass<>();

        Child<Long> child = Child.builder() 
                .someGenericClass(someGenericClass) // error: The method someGenericClass(SomeGenericClass<?,Parent<Object>>) in
                // the type Parent.ParentBuilder<Object,capture#1-of ?,capture#2-of ?> is
                // not applicable for the arguments (SomeGenericClass<String,Parent<Long>>)
                .value(10L) // error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from capture#1-of ? to Child<Long>
                .build();
    }
}
```

If works, as soon as the child itself no longer has a generic parameter. So having the child like this, everything compiles and works perfectly fine:

```
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
final class Child extends Parent<Long> {

}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it not possible to have generic `final` classes when using the `@SuperBuilder`?

Comment: Since generics are flattened out at compile time, lombok might not have an idea of what exactly you want the builder to accept in T. If you can avoid overusing generics, please do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type parameter for `builder()` (which represents what kind of `Child` you are creating) is not inferred correctly. The compiler thinks it's `Object`. To fix the error, just make it very clear what kind of `Child.Builder` you are creating, e.g.

```
Child.<Long>builder()
    ...
```

The reason for why this cannot be inferred is similar to why [chaining `thenComparing`s breaks type inference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24436871/5133585).

You can see something similar happen with simple builders too:

```
@Builder
final class Foo<T> {
    private T t;
}

// error here!
Foo<Long> f = Foo.builder().t(1L).build();
```

Though in simple cases like that, the error message is a lot clearer, saying that you cannot convert a `Foo<Object>` to `Foo<Long>`.

Your case is more complicated - you have a `SomeGenericClass<?, Parent<T>>` field. That means `someGenericClass()` is expecting a `SomeGenericClass<?, Parent<Object>>`. A `SomeGenericClass<String, Parent<Long>>` certainly can't be passed to that.  And the fact that you're using `SuperBuilder` makes things even more complicated.