# How to define classes for several computation steps to use Type inference in Java?

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

How to change the code below to get type inference?
The line

```
 Integer b = run().task1(()->555).task2((a)->a+5);
```

Does not compile, because compiler can't conclude that `a` is Integer.

```
class MyTest {

    @Test
    void testWithTwoTasks() {
            Integer b = run().task1(()->555).task2((a)->a+5);
    }

    public <T, R> MyTasksRunner<T, R> run() {
             return new MyTasksRunner<>();
    }

    public static class MyTasksRunner<T, R> {
         public MyStep1<T, R> task1(Callable<T> task1) {
             return new MyStep1<>(task1);
         }
    }

    public static class MyStep1<T,R>  {

         private Callable<T> step1;

         MyStep1 (Callable<T> task) {
            this.step1 = task;
         }

        public R task2(Function<T,R> task) throws Exception {
            return task.apply(step1.call());
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: [`Comparator.thenComparing` has the same problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24436871/5133585) Java's type inference just can't figure this out. How about adding some explicit types or dividing up the chain?

Comment: Yes, adding explicit types helps, but I hoped that I can avoid this :(

Comment: That said, it appears that `MyTasksRunner` doesn't need to be generic at all, and that `MyStep1` can just take one type parameter instead of 2. Would that work for you?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, probably. I created this example from another one, real code, so may be there is something redundant.

Comment: Yeah. I would suggest [edit]ing your question so that it is more similar to your real code. The code you've shown just seems to be simple function composition (reinventing `Function.andThen`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the *type-parameters*, for the *run* method.

```java
void testWithTwoTasks() throws Exception {
    Integer b = this.<Integer, Integer>run().task1(()->555).task2((a)->a+5);
}
```