# Java: How to give priority to a category if price is same?

Tags: java, arrays, selection-sort

I need to sort out the following array-

```
“Blouse” “W” 21 17.95
“Blouse” “C” 35 17.95
“Shirt”  “M” 13 21.95
“Pants”  “W” 22 67.95
“Pants”  “M” 22 62.95
“Pants”  “C” 26 21.95
“Coat”   “C” 20 21.95
“Coat”   “M” 10 62.95
“Blouse” “W” 21 17.95
“Blouse” “C” 35 17.95
“Shirt”  “M” 13 21.95
“Pants”  “W” 22 67.95
“Pants”  “M” 22 62.95
“Pants”  “C” 26 21.95
“Coat”   “C” 20 21.95
“Coat”   “M” 10 62.95
```

If the prices are same, I need to give priority to C before W, and W before M. I need to use selection sorting for this program, and it's as follows-

```
public static void selectionSort (Comparable[] list, int n)
{
    int min;
    Comparable temp;

    for (int i = 0; i< n - 1;i++)
    {
        min =  i;

        for(int scan = i + 1; scan < n; scan++)
        {
            if (list[i].compareTo(list[scan]) < 0)
                min = scan;
        }

       temp = list[min];
       list[min] = list[i];
       list[i] = temp;

    }
```

I am having problems when the prices are equal, my compareTo method is as follows. I am thinking of using sentinel values to give priority to these categories, but how would I do that? Also, what should the sorting algorithm do, having all these sentinel values for different categories while going through the whole array. How should it pick the proper (C before W, w before M) object to swap?

```
public int compareTo(Object obj)
{
    int result;
    double objPrice = ((Item)obj).getPrice();
    char objCategory = ((Item)obj).getCategory().charAt(1);

    if (objPrice == price)
    //         {
    //             if(objCategory.charAt(1) == 'M')
    //             return result = 0;
    //             else
    //             return result = 1;
    //         }
        switch (objCategory)
        {
            case 'C':
            return -1;
        }
    else
        return result = (int)(objPrice - price);

}
```

Comment: You could do two sort run throughs, one that sorts on price, the second will check for groups of equal values and re-sort those groups individually based on categories.

Answer (score 0):

Make a third field that holds priority of W M C and sort on multiple keys.
[Sorting Java objects using multiple keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036429/sorting-java-objects-using-multiple-keys)

Answer (score 0):

instead of the switch statement, you'll have to make if statements:

```
public int compareTo(Object obj)
{
    int result;
    double objPrice = ((Item)obj).getPrice();
    char objCategory = ((Item)obj).getCategory().charAt(1);

    if (objPrice == price) {
        if(category == objCategory) {
            return name.compareTo(((Item)obj).getName()); // if we have the same category, we need to decide somehow
        }
        if(category == "C") return 1; // C always beats everything
        if(objCategory == "C" ) return -1;

        if(category == "M") return -1; // M always looses
        if(objCategory == "M") return 1;
    } else {
        return result = (int)(objPrice - price);
    }

}
```

This does cover all 6 possible combinations of cetegories:

```
C - C => they are the same
C - W => one is C
C - M => one is C
W - C => one is C
W - W => they are the same 
W - M => one is M
M - C => one is C
M - W => one is M
M - M => they are the same
```

Comment: If categories are the same we need to decide what?

Comment: We need to decide what to return. And because all items have a name, I figured it would be best to sort them alphabetically then. If they do have the same price, category and name however, it will assume it is the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Your compareTo is not complete. You need to compare the categories of the two items.

Inside the if (objPrice == price) add something like:

```
if (objCat == 'C')
      return cat == 'C' ? 0 : -1

  if (objCat == 'W')
      return cat == 'C' 
         ? 1
         : (cat == 'W')
            ? 0
            : -1

  if (objCat == 'M')
     ... Check for three possibilities
```

To simplify the comparison, add a mapping from category to an integer (e.g. Using a map). This will make your comparison look more like this:

```
if (objPrice == price)
   return mappedValueOf(cat1) - mappedValueOf(cat2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) you can use the Streaming API:s combined with `Comparator.comparing` and `Comparator.thenComparing` to make the sorting work.

If you assume the following `Item` class:

```
public class Item {
    private final String category;
    private final String name;
    private final double price;
    private final int size;

    public Item(
            final String name, 
            final String category, 
            final int size, 
            final double price) {

        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
        this.size = size;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item: [" +
                Objects.toString(name) + " " +
                Objects.toString(category) + " " +
                Objects.toString(price) + " " +
                Objects.toString(size) + "]";
    }
}
```

Then, the sorting can be done like this:

```
final List<Item> items = Arrays.asList(
        new Item("Blouse", "W", 21, 20.95),
        new Item("Blouse", "W", 21, 17.95),
        new Item("Blouse", "M", 21, 17.95),
        new Item("Blouse", "C", 21, 17.95));

final List<String> categoryPrioOrder = Arrays.asList("C", "W", "M");

final List<Item> sorted = items.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Item::getPrice)
                .thenComparing(
                        Item::getCategory,
                        (c1, c2) -> categoryPrioOrder.indexOf(c1) - categoryPrioOrder.indexOf(c2)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(sorted);
```

The output will be (as per the OPs specification):

> [Item: [Blouse C 17.95 21], Item: [Blouse W 17.95 21], Item: [Blouse M 17.95 21], Item: [Blouse W 20.95 21]]