# How to send multiple arguments to compareTo to filter Sorting type and sort by in Java?

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

I am not using Java 8 but Java 6

I want to send argument to program to sort

1) (by Quantity) or (by desc) and

2) in ascending or descending.

Unable to get idea how to implement this check in  compareTo()

Following is Javacode:

```
package no.java6.listsort;
public class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit>{

private int quantity;
private String desc;

public Fruit()
{   
}
public Fruit(String desc, int quantity)
{
    this.desc = desc;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Fruit o) {
    return o.getDesc().compareTo(this.getDesc());
//here i want to add if condition; To Sort on what and to sort by ascending or descending
}
}
```

Following is execution code:

```
package no.java6.listsort;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Execute {

public void implement()
{
    List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<>();
    Fruit f1 = new Fruit("Sachin",80);
    Fruit f2 = new Fruit("Anjali",70);
    Fruit f3 = new Fruit("Harpreet",90);
    Fruit f4 = new Fruit("Rupinder",100);
    fruits.add(f1);
    fruits.add(f2);
    fruits.add(f3);
    fruits.add(f4);
    for(int i=0;i<fruits.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Desc = "+fruits.get(i).getDesc()+"; Quantiity: "+fruits.get(i).getQuantity());
    }
    Collections.sort(fruits);
    for(int i=0;i<fruits.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Desc = "+fruits.get(i).getDesc()+"; Quantiity: "+fruits.get(i).getQuantity());
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    new Execute().implement();
}
}
```

Comment: I believe you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036429/sorting-java-objects-using-multiple-keys

Answer (score 8):

If you like to sort in different ways you need many different comparators or one dynamic comparator.
Here an example of dynamic comparator:

```
public class DynamicFruitComparator implements Comparator<Fruit>{
    private static int compareBy = 0;

    public DynamicFruitComparator(int compareBy) {
        this.compareBy = compareBy;
    }

    public DinamycComparator compareBy(int compareBy) {
        this.compareBy = compareBy;
        return this;
    }

    public int compare(Fruit a, Fruit b) {
        if (compareBy == 0) {
            return .... // First criteria
        } else if (compareBy == 1) {
            return .... // Second criteria
        }
    }
}
```

To use it simply

```
DynamicFruitComparator d0 = new DynamicFruitComparator (0);
DynamicFruitComparator d1 = new DynamicFruitComparator (1);

List<Fruit> list = ....

Collections.sort(list, d0); // To sort by criteria 0

Collections.sort(list, d1); // To sort by criteria 1
```

If you don't like to create ten different comparators you can reuse the same dinamyc comparator setting the sort criteria each time.

```
DynamicFruitComparator d = new DynamicFruitComparator (0);

List<Fruit> list = ....

Collections.sort(list, d); // To sort by criteria 0
...
Collections.sort(list, d.compareBy(1)); // To sort by criteria 1
...
Collections.sort(list, d.compareBy(5)); // To sort by criteria 5
...
Collections.sort(list, d.compareBy(0)); // Again with criteria 0
```

Comment: But there are 10 value in bean to sort and according to it i need to implement 10 conditions. with ascending and descending too. Can we simplify that ?

Comment: You can also use just one instance of DynamicFruitComparator setting the compareBy value before ordering. I edit the answer to add it

Comment: @fatherazrael, check out Panther's comment... Its much easier if your using Java 8... Otherwise use 10 comparator objects instead of using conditions in the same object... It will be cleaner...

Comment: @Codebender 
unfortunately, It is not Java 8

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one way to sort your list using the `compareTo` method, this is what you call natural ordering. For other cases, you can supply a comparator to the Collections.sort method.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I see that your `Fruit` class implements `Comparable` interface. This should be used if you are sure about the natural ordering of the `Fruit` object. If natural ordering is not clear(which can be in many cases), you can make a custom `Comparator` and use it to sort.

If you implement `Comparable`, simply using `Collections.sort(list)` will work. If you use a custom `Comparator`, you can pass it to the overloaded method `Collections.sort(list, comparator)`.

Refer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom [Comporator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) classes. Example:

```
class SortedByName implements Comparator<Product> {      
       public int compare(Product obj1, Product obj2) {            
             String str1 = obj1.getName();
             String str2 = obj2.getName();            
             return str1.compareTo(str2);
       }
}

class SortedByPrice implements Comparator<Product> {      
       public int compare(Product obj1, Product obj2) {            
             double price1 = obj1.getPrice();
             double price2 = obj2.getPrice();
             if(price1 > price2) {
                    return 1;
             }
             else if(price1 < price2) {
                    return -1;
             }
             else {
                    return 0;
             }
       }
}
```

and use it

```
Arrays.sort(p, new SortedByName());
```