# Passing an argument to a Comparator - Java

Tags: java, sorting

I have a Comparator class and in its `compareTo` method it accesses a value from a HashMap. I was wondering if there was a way to pass the name of the key to the `compareTo`method. Here is my code. For example in this code I want to pass `"racesWon"`

```
public static Comparator<Player> RacesWon = new Comparator<Player>() {
    public int compare(Player p1, Player p2) {
        Integer p1GamesWon = Integer.valueOf(p1.stats.get("racesWon"));
        Integer p2GamesWon = Integer.valueOf(p2.stats.get("racesWon"));
        return p2GamesWon.compareTo(p1GamesWon);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a much simpler way of creating your comparator:

```
racesWon = Comparator.comparingInt(p -> Integer.valueOf(p.stats.get("racesWon")));
```

Of if you want a method that generates a comparator based on a given key:

```
Comparator<Player> getComparator(String key) {
    return Comparator.comparingInt(p -> Integer.parseInt(p.stats.get(key)));
}
```

Comment: I believe the second version is what he wants. Thanks for nice work

Comment: There's a lot of boxing and unboxing going on here - for `comparingInt` use `parseInt` to avoid this. It's also worth noting that each value will be parsed, on average, `lg n` times - this is rather inefficient.

Comment: @BoristheSpider changed it to parseInt as suggested. Agree on the inefficiency: the answer would be to store the values as integers rather than strings which is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31199171/852795 is a much better answer if you'd like to see it implemented in a form similar to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest change from your anonymous class is using a variable:

```
String key = "racesWon";
Comparator<Player> RacesWon = new Comparator<Player>() {
    public int compare(Player p1, Player p2) {
        Integer p1GamesWon = Integer.valueOf(p1.stats.get(key));
        Integer p2GamesWon = Integer.valueOf(p2.stats.get(key));
        return p2GamesWon.compareTo(p1GamesWon);
    }
};
```

You just have to be careful as your comparator may be stuck with the key. The best place to create the above comparator would be the method that sets the key.

There are  functional ways to create that comparator, which make your code even more concise:

```
String key = "racesWon";
Comparator<Player> c = 
    Comparator.comparingInt(p -> Integer.parseInt(p.stats.get(key)));

//yet another way:
Comparator<Player> ccc = 
    Comparator.comparing(player -> Integer.valueOf(player.stats.get(key)),
        Integer::compare);
```