# Coordinate DataType for Operation in Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the collection of tweets in a json file. I want to do operations on them such as grouping tweets based on the time and coordinates that each data entry have. currently for the object coordinates I have them in List data type. Similar with the time and date. So I have successfully parse them, but its very difficult for me to do operations on them particular for the data-time and coordinates.

The ultimate goal is so that I can do operation on them more easily.

1. How do I convert this the List data type into so that they store double?
2. Im not sure what data type should I use for the time and date

**this is an example of the json element**

```
{"text": "Flood/Storm/Tree Down. Northern Beaches (King Rd, Ingleside, NSW 2101) at 6 Mar 2017 21:38, 
"user": {"id": "4721717942", "name": "NSW Fire Updates"}, "lang": "en", 
"coordinates": { "coordinates": [151.264811, -33.6848] , "type":"Point"}, "created_at": "Mon Mar 06 10:44:31 +0000 2017"}
```

**this is the class for coordinates that I have made**

```
public class Coordinates {
    private String type;
    private List<String> coordinates;
    public String getType (){
        return type;
    }
    public void setType (String type){
        this.type = type;
    }
    public List<String> getCoordinates(){
        return coordinates;
    }
    public void setCoordinates (List<String> coordinates){
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }


 @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "[type = "+type+", coordinates = "+coordinates+"]";
     }
}
```

**this is the class which have time and date in them**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Tweet {
    private String text;
    private String created_at;
    private User user;
    private Coordinates coordinates;

    public Tweet(){
    }

    public String getText()
    {
        return text;
    }
    public void setText(String text)
    {
        this.text = text;
    }
    public String getCreated_at()
    {
        return created_at;
    }
    public void setCreated_at(String created_at)
    {
        this.created_at = created_at;
    }
    public User getUser()
    {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user)
    {
        this.user = user;
    }
    public Coordinates getCoordinates()
    {
        return coordinates;
    }
    public void setCoordinates(Coordinates coordinates)
    {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "[text = "+text+", created_at = "+created_at+", user = "+user+", coordinates = "+coordinates+"]";
    }
}
```

Comment: What JSON library are you using?

Comment: its jackson library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try understanding java 8 stream map and filter operations and you can do your thing in a single line of code. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html or if you can't use java 8 try this example from this thread [Sorting Java objects using multiple keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036429/sorting-java-objects-using-multiple-keys)

Comment: HI, Im actually not allowed to use Java 8

Comment: Do you have any problems or something more you need? if no please give me the answer and lets continue. if yes - tell me what do you need? you need get the coordinates double values?

Comment: Sorry I had a meeting. For the coordinate class. the object I change from List<String> to List<Double> it worked aswell. But is this okay?