# JSTL foreach - sort list with particular field

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am displaying below 3 fields userid,value & upadtetime in which I want to sort by UPDATE.TIME in desc order. Please suggest how to do this.

```
<c:forEach var="comment" items="${document['kcmeta/comment']}">

<g2:out value="${mm:MasterValue('datamodel_userInfo',comment.USER_ID)}"/>

<c:out value="${comment.VALUE}" />

<span class="searhResultLightGrayText"><c:out value="${comment.UPDATE_DATE}" /></span>          
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that you can sort any kind of collections by using the `c:forEach` **JSTL** tag, However you can handle this with the usage of **Scriplets** and embed JAVA code into your JSP.

```
<%
    Collections.sort(yourList, new Comparator<Document>() {
        public int compare (Document d1, Document d2) {
            return d1.getUpdateTime().compare(d2.getUpdateTime());
        }
    });
%>
```

and then you'll be able to iterate over your sorted list:

```
<c:forEach var="comment" items="<%=youList%>">
    ...
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: This is not the best way to do this. See the discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638550/how-can-i-sort-a-list-several-different-ways-in-a-jsp

Comment: @GabiM: Agree, It is not the best way to handle it, however I just exposed another way, not necessarily the best one to follow.

Comment: Sure, it does the job. I just commented for others to know there are better alternatives